# Java: “Could not find the main class. Program will exit”

Tags: java

I am getting `Java: “Could not find the main class. Program will exit”` when i am running compiled jar files.

What causes this error and how do I avoid it?

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1 IDE and java 1.6

Comment: Make sure you have defined a `public static void main(String args[])` function in some class of your project. If you have made it, then right click the file and select **Run File**.

Comment: How are you running the program ?

Comment: @Santosh: When i do debug through Netbeans it works fine, but after creating compiled build and using that jar i am getting above error. This is for y previous applications also which was working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your manifest is malformed. Usually the programmer dont deal with this files when using an IDE but maybe you found a bug.

Read this documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Take a deep look to "Setting an Application's Entry Point" section. Maybe that's the problem.